# Does executing a bash command successfully in Ruby return a true boolean object?

Tags: ruby, bash, command, boolean

This is something I have been curious about for a while. When a bash  command is executed in Ruby (e.g. w/ ` usage), does it return a true boolean value upon completion and false if it fails? Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `system()` to perform the command, you will get `false` or `nil` on failure (dependant on what failed),  and `true` on success.

If you use `Backticks` however, the result will be whatever the shelled-out program wrote to `STDOUT`.

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands

Comment: So, just to clarify, while using system() if the command executes but doesn't complete w/out an error false will be returned, and if the command executes but doesn't complete because of an error nil will be returned. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

In general there are four approaches to execute a command in Ruby and treat STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR differently.

```
# Kernel#system
# returns true (zero exit status), false (non zero exit status) or nil (command execution fails)

# Kernel#`  (backticks)
# returns the STDOUT
# outputs the STDERR, but not capture it
# The built-in syntax %x{...} uses this method

# IO#popen
# the STDIN and STDOUT will be connected to the returned IO object

# Open3#popen3
# STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR are all captured to IO objects
```

And you can still handle STDERR separately in the original command, like:

```
system("[command_which_fails]") #=> STDERR & false
system("[command_which_fails] > /dev/null 2>&1") #=> false
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Using this alongside Aaron Cronin's method will prove to be very beneficial!

Answer (score 0):

Backquotes ` ` will not return true or false but that does not mean you can not check for the successful execution of command. You can always use $? it returns you the error code. If the last command ran successfully  it should be 0.

You can use system(' '). It returns true or false depending on the result of your command.

You can use many ways to execute commands in ruby. Most of them are explained in following article.

[5 ways to run shell commands in Ruby](http://www.brownfort.com/2014/08/execute-commands-ruby/)

Answer (score -2):

It should return `nil` when fails and `true` upon success.

Comment: `\`echo 'foo'\` #=> "foo\n"`

Comment: You are confusing `` with `Kernel#system`